# Reading MultiGeometry KML file using Geopandas

Tags: kml, geopandas, google-earth, fiona

I have a kml file with multi-geometries (points and polygons). I want to access only the polygons present inside the kml file.

I tried reading the kml file using Geopandas-

`inputfile = 'path to kml file' fiona.supported_drivers['KML'] = 'rw' sp = gpd.read_file(inputfile, driver='KML')`

here 'sp' variable only reads the point features present inside the kml file. I tried using 'Geometry' argument along with the driver argument, but still only the point features are read.

Can anyone help me in accessing the 'Polygon' entities in the kml file?

Comment: Could you provide a sample of your data? It could be that the polygon entities are a different layer of the KML and you only read the first part containing point features (see also here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/328525/geopandas-read-file-only-reading-first-part-of-kml)

Answer (score 3):

I had this same question today! I was obtaining the KML through a URL response however, so I was able to "remove" the point data prior to writing it as a kml file (now only with polygon data). This is what I did:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import geopandas as gpd
import fiona
fiona.drvsupport.supported_drivers['kml'] = 'rw'
fiona.drvsupport.supported_drivers['KML'] = 'rw'

soup = bs(r.content, 'xml')  # kml/xml content obtained from hitting an API
child = soup.find_all('Placemark')
child_polys = []

# Creates list of only polygon feature data
for c in child:
    if c.find('Point') == None:
        child_polys.append(c)

# Add required header/footer to the polygon data, then join below. 
header = ['''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
 <Document>
  <open>
   1
  </open>''']

header.extend(child_polys)
header.append('''</Document>
</kml>''')

with open('temp_data.kml', 'w') as f:
    f.write(''.join([str(x) for x in header]))

data = gpd.read_file(r"temp_data.kml", driver="kml")
```

This got me a geodataframe with a column of names, description and geometry for the polygons only. In your case, you may have to find a way to read in the kml, then edit it as I did above, before reconstructing and passing to geopandas. Good luck.

Comment: What is `r` in  `bs(r.content, 'xml')`?

Comment: The "response" from an API data pull. In any case, the first responder's link provided some good info as well. The method I used worked for me.